# What exactly does this format string do when paired with fscanf?

Tags: c, scanf, c-strings, format-specifiers, conversion-specifier

I am looking at some code and came across this line:

```
fscanf(file, "%*[: ]%16s", dest);
```

What does the `%*[: ]%16s` format string specifier do?

Comment: I feel like the best answer to your question as written must ostensibly be any [documentation page](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) for fscanf format specifiers.  So I'm going to downvote (based on lack of research) unless you came across something in some documentation you specifically need clarified or don't understand, in which case, please clarify in your question what you do or do not understand about existing documentation for format specifiers.

Comment: @Wyck As far as I know sometimes even senior programmers have not read the C or C++ Standard in their lifes.

Comment: If even simple research capabilities like asking the web about scanf format strings are missing on many questions, additionally without any sign of some own effort, it correctly leads to downvotes. You might need to take the [tour] again. The bad reputation reflects back to the ones abusing SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This format string

```
"%*[: ]%16s"
```

means that all symbols `':'` and `' '` (the symbols placed in the square brackets in the format string) must be skipped in the input stream and then at most 16 characters be read in a character array.

In the format string the symbol `*` is assignment-suppressing character.

Here is a demonstration program. For visibility I am using `sscanf` instead of `fscanf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    const char *stream = "::: : : : :::Hello";
    char s[17];
    
    sscanf( stream, "%*[: ]%16s", s );
    
    printf( "\"%s\"\n", s );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
"Hello"
```

Answer (score 2):

It reads in any spaces or `:` (colon) characters then discards them and then reads up to 16 non-whitespace characters into `dest` (17 including the null terminator `\0`).

The `*` after the `%` is the "assignment-suppression character."
The number between `%` and `s` is the "maximum field width."
The square brackets indicate to match either the characters within or everything except those characters (with a caret). Dash and caret are handled specially.

From the Linux manpage for scanf:

> Each conversion specification in format begins with either the character '%' or the character  sequence  "%n$"
> (see below for the distinction) followed by:
>
> ·      An  optional  '*'  **assignment-suppression  character:** scanf() reads input as directed by the conversion
> specification, but discards the input.  No corresponding pointer argument is required, and this  specification is not included in the count of successful assignments returned by scanf().
> [snip]
>
> ·      An  optional  decimal  integer  which  specifies  the **maximum field width.** Reading of characters stops
> either when this maximum is reached or when a nonmatching character is found, whichever happens  first.
> Most  conversions  discard  initial  white space characters (the exceptions are noted below), and these
> discarded characters don't count toward the maximum field width.  String input conversions store a terminating  null  byte ('\0') to mark the end of the input; the maximum field width does not include this terminator.

> The following conversion specifiers are available:
>
> [snip]
>
> **s**      Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next pointer must be a  pointer  to  the  initial element  of  a  character array that is long enough to hold the input sequence and the terminating null byte ('\0'), which is added automatically.  The input string stops at white space  or  at  the  maximum                 field width, whichever occurs first.
>
> [snip]
>
> **[**      Matches a nonempty sequence of characters from the specified  set  of  accepted  characters;  the  next pointer  must be a pointer to char, and there must be enough room for all the characters in the string, plus a terminating null byte.  The usual skip of leading white space is suppressed.  The string  is  to                 be  made up of characters in (or not in) a particular set; the set is defined by the characters between the open bracket [ character and a close bracket ] character.  The set excludes those characters if the first  character  after  the  open bracket is a circumflex (^).  To include a close bracket in the set, make it the first character after the open bracket or the circumflex; any other position will  end  the                 set.   The  hyphen  character  - is also special; when placed between two other characters, it adds all intervening characters to the set.  To include a hyphen, make it the last character  before  the  final close  bracket.   For  instance,  [^]0-9-] means the set "everything except close bracket, zero through nine, and hyphen".  The string ends with the appearance of a character not in the (or, with  a  circumflex, in) set or when the field width runs out.

– Linux manpage for [scanf(3)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)

Answer (score 0):

> What does the `"%*[: ]%16s"` format string specifier do?

1. `"%*[: ]"`: read and discard (due to the `"*"`) **at least one** of input characters of the *scan_set* : `':'`,  `' '`. If no `':'`,  `' '` found, stop scan.
2. `"%16s"` has 3 steps: 1) Read and discard any (0 or more) leading white-spaces.  e.g. `' '`, `'\n'`, `'\t'`, etc.  2) Read and save to `dest` **at least one** but no more than 16 non-white-spaces - else stop scan. 3) Append a *null character* to `dest`.  Thus `dest` should be at least 17: `char dest[16+1];`

---

**Advanced**

A curious difference of `fscanf()` and `sscanf()` is that when `sscanf()` reads a *null character*, scanning stops.  With `fscanf()`, scanning continues.

With `fscanf(file "%s", dest)` and 8 character file data of `'\t'`,`'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, `'\0'`, `'x'`, `'y'`, `'z'`, `dest[]` will get `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, `'\0'`, `'x'`, `'y'`, `'z'`, `'\0'`.  It is unusual to have a *null character* in a text file.